# how to redirect a file upload request from node js to another server which is tomcat (servlet)?

Tags: node.js, express, tomcat

I have a scenario where i have to collect a file from express server ,and redirect the request along with the file to the tomcat server

```
var http= require('http');
 var request=require('request');
 var formidable=require('formidable');
 var fs=require('fs');
 var form= new formidable.IncomingForm();

 RunnerURL="http://localhost:8080";
 form.parse(req,function(err,fields,files){
    var oldpath=files.fileToUpload;
    console.log("request"+files.fileToUpload.name);
})

var newurl='https://localhost:8080/fileHandler';
request(newurl).pipe(res);
```

but this is giving some errors can somebody help me

1.Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http://localhost http://localhost:8080
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
2.cant set headers after they are sent

Comment: what errors ?..